# Get result of redirection as the client (curl)

Tags: php, url, redirect, curl

I'm trying to get the "true" url behind a redirection, i have no trouble getting the url with curl, my problem is that the link returned by curl is only valid for the server's IP address.

Now i'm looking for something to get the real url "as the client", without java or flash, and i have no idea how to do it to be honest.

My current code:

```
function get_url( $url ) {
$res = array();
$options = array( 
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
    CURLOPT_HEADER          => false,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  => true,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT       => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER     => true,
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT  => 120,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT         => 120,
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS       => 10,
); 
$ch      = curl_init( $url ); 
curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options ); 
$content = curl_exec( $ch ); 
$err     = curl_errno( $ch ); 
$errmsg  = curl_error( $ch ); 
$header  = curl_getinfo( $ch ); 
curl_close( $ch ); 
$res['content'] = $content;     
return $res;
```

}

Comment: If they go through the trouble of making data available only to the originally requesting client via IP address, then I suppose they don’t _want_ you to do what you’re trying to do …?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible through CURL. The server probably generates the link based on your IP address. You can not override your IP address with client's through curl. So try to use other methods you have mentioned on the question.

Comment: I know it's not possible through curl, i'm asking for other solutions beside java/flash because this has to work on mobile devices